# How do i install "Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller" driver on linux?

Tags: linux, audio, intel

The problem is that when I plug in my headphones, my mic doesn't work but I can hear sounds through the headphones.

My system info:

- Distro: MX-Linux (XFCE)
- Motherboard: Asus PRIME B660M-A D4

I have an onboard intel audio device:

```bash
$ lspci | grep -i audio
>> 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller (rev 11)
```

```bash
$ lsmod | grep snd_intel_hdmi
>>
```

More info:

```
System: Kernel: 5.18.0-4mx-amd64 [5.18.16-1~mx21+1] x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1
parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.18.0-4mx-amd64
root=UUID=<filter> ro quiet splash init=lib/systemd/systemd
Desktop: Xfce 4.18.0 tk: Gtk 3.24.24 info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm 4.18.0 vt: 7
dm: LightDM 1.26.0 Distro: MX-21.3_ahs_x64 Wildflower September 18 2022
base: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Machine: Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: N/A v: N/A serial: <filter>
Mobo: ASUSTeK model: PRIME B660M-A D4 v: Rev 1.xx serial: <filter>
UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1620 date: 08/12/2022

CPU: Info: 8-Core model: 12th Gen Intel Core i5-12600K bits: 64 type: MT MCP
arch: Alder Lake family: 6 model-id: 97 (151) stepping: 2 microcode: 23 cache:
L2: 20 MiB
flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 117964
Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/4900 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800 4: 800
5: 800 6: 801 7: 800 8: 800 9: 801 10: 801 11: 800 12: 801 13: 800 14: 801 15: 798
16: 801
Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected
Type: l1tf status: Not affected
Type: mds status: Not affected
Type: meltdown status: Not affected
Type: mmio_stale_data status: Not affected
Type: retbleed status: Not affected
Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Type: spectre_v2
mitigation: Enhanced IBRS, IBPB: conditional, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS: SW sequence
Type: srbds status: Not affected
Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected

Graphics: Device-1: Intel AlderLake-S GT1 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0
chip-ID: 8086:4680 class-ID: 0300
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.14 compositor: xfwm4 v: 4.18.0 driver:
loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa display-ID: :0.0 screens: 1
Screen-1: 0 s-res: 2560x1080 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 677x285mm (26.7x11.2")
s-diag: 735mm (28.9")
Monitor-1: HDMI-3 res: 2560x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 96 size: 677x290mm (26.7x11.4")
diag: 736mm (29")
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL-S GT1) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5 direct render: Yes

Audio: Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-S HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
alternate: snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:7ad0 class-ID: 0403
Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.18.0-4mx-amd64 running: yes
Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 14.2 running: yes

Network: Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-V vendor: ASUSTeK driver: e1000e v: kernel port: efa0
bus-ID: 00:1f.6 chip-ID: 8086:1a1d class-ID: 0200
IF: eth0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
IF-ID-1: br-888bb581050e state: down mac: <filter>
IF-ID-2: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>

RAID: Hardware-1: Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller driver: vmd v: 0.6
port: 5000 bus-ID: 00:0e.0 chip-ID: 8086.467f rev: class-ID: 0104

Drives: Local Storage: total: 447.13 GiB used: 158.03 GiB (35.3%)
SMART Message: Unable to run smartctl. Root privileges required.
ID-1: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37480G size: 447.13 GiB
block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: SSD serial: <filter>
rev: 0107 scheme: GPT

Partition: ID-1: / raw-size: 438.87 GiB size: 430.91 GiB (98.19%) used: 158.03 GiB (36.7%)
fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 maj-min: 8:2
ID-2: /boot/efi raw-size: 256 MiB size: 252 MiB (98.46%) used: 274 KiB (0.1%) fs: vfat
dev: /dev/sda1 maj-min: 8:1

Swap: Kernel: swappiness: 15 (default 60) cache-pressure: 100 (default)
ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 8 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 dev: /dev/sda3
maj-min: 8:3

Sensors: System Temperatures: cpu: 27.8 C mobo: N/A
Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A

Repos: Packages: 2258 note: see --pkg apt: 2210 lib: 1111 flatpak: 6 snap: 42
No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/connectify.list
1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/connectify-archive-keyring.gpg] http://apt.connectify.me/ speedify main
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-stable-updates.list
1: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list
1: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
2: deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
1: deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mx.list
1: deb https://mxlinux.grena.ge/mxlinux/mx/repo/ bullseye main non-free
2: deb https://mxlinux.grena.ge/mxlinux/mx/repo/ bullseye ahs
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x bullseye main
2: deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x bullseye main
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list
1: deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/protonvpn-stable.list
1: deb [arch="all", signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/protonvpn-stable-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable main
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list
1: deb https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/ jessie main
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list
1: deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-lunar.list
1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu lunar main
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/uget-team-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list
1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/uget-team/ppa/ubuntu kinetic main
No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unityhub.list
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/v2raya.list
1: deb https://apt.v2raya.org/ v2raya main
No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list
Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/waydroid.list
1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/waydroid.gpg] https://repo.waydro.id/ jammy main

Info: Processes: 369 Uptime: 1h 46m wakeups: 0 Memory: 15.38 GiB used: 5.22 GiB (33.9%)
Init: systemd v: 247 runlevel: 5 default: 5 tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: 10.2.1
alt: 10 Client: shell wrapper v: 5.1.4-release inxi: 3.3.06

Boot Mode: UEFI
```

Comment: Generally speaking it's either supported in the kernel or it isn't. What's the problem exactly? Please [edit] the question to describe it.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, Edited.

Comment: *my mic doesn't work but I can hear sounds through the headphones*... How are the headphones connected? The board requires a separated audio out and audio in. If the headphones have a single jack, typical for phones and tablets and some laptops, then only the headphones work, not the microphone. You'd need a splitter cable for it to work. Nothing to do with drivers.